# Tomcat 8 Unicode filename war file deploy issue

Tags: java, tomcat, unicode, tomcat8, opensuse

On Linux(openSUSE) machine I'm trying to deploy on Tomcat 8 application(war file) that contains a files with names with Unicode characters.

Inside of the war file the name looks like:

```
бжк-природний-1496336830201.xml
```

but after deploy the file looks like:

```
???-?????????????-1496336830201.xml
```

How to tell Tomcat to properly deploy the file names ?

**UPDATED**

This is a sample war file with Unicode file name inside: [war file](http://www.thedownloadplanet.com/files/api.war)

What is wrong with the file name of the file inside in this war ?

**UPDATED**

I have installed `unzip-rcc` as it was suggested here https://superuser.com/questions/1215670/opensuse-unzip-unicode-issue and now unzip(console command) on the WAR file is working fine but Tomcat still deploy the files with the same issue.

Comment: If you unzip the war into a directory, does the filename with special characters preserved? Another thing to try is to ensure JAVA has the right encoding.

Comment: yeah.. unzip kills the filenames

Comment: This suggests that the Operating System does not have the font or character set to handle such encoding. So its not Java fault :)

Comment: yes, but I have no idea what can be wrong. Is it also possible that my Jenkins/Maven build destroys the file names ? If zip/unzip raw files downloaded from Git  - everything works fine.. only files from war file generated by Jenkins/Maven doesn't work properly.

Comment: I have installed unzip-rcc as it was suggested here https://superuser.com/questions/1215670/opensuse-unzip-unicode-issue and now unzip(console command) on the WAR file is working fine but Tomcat still deploy the files with the same issue. How to configure Tomcat 8 in order to properly deploy the files ?

Comment: Try putting these settings in Tomcat startup script: `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting these settings in Tomcat startup script:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
```

From experience, Java will print up-side-down question mark for characters it does not know how to encode.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I was struggling with this issue for a few days and now with your help it is solved! I have added these properties to my tomcat.conf file

Answer (score 2):

The filename is indeed in UTF-8 in the zip .war file.

```
try (ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
    zipFile.stream()
        .forEachOrdered(entry -> System.out.printf("- %s%n", entry.getName()));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However the zip does not has added the encoding (as `bytes[] extra` information).

Three solutions would be imaginable:

- One short solution might be to run TomCat under a UTF-8 locale.
- The best would be to have maven build a war with UTF-8 encoding. (`<onfiguration><encoding>UTF-8</encoding></configuration>`)
- Repairing the war by converting it.

With the first two solutions I have no experience. A quick search didn't yield anything ("encoding" is a bit ubiquitous).

The repair code is simple:

```
Path path = Paths.get(".../api.war").toAbsolutePath().normalize();
Path path2 = Paths.get(".../api2.war").toAbsolutePath().normalize();

URI uri = URI.create("jar:file://" + path.toString());
Map<String,String> env = new HashMap<String,String>();
env.put("create", "false");
env.put("encoding", "UTF-8");

URI uri2 = URI.create("jar:file://" + path2.toString());
Map<String,String> env2 = new HashMap<String,String>();
env2.put("create", "true");
env2.put("encoding", "UTF-8");

try (FileSystem zipFS = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env);
     FileSystem zipFS2 = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri2, env2)) {

    Files.walkFileTree(zipFS.getPath("/"), new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
                    throws IOException {
            System.out.println("* File: " + file);
            Path file2 = zipFS2.getPath(file.toString());
            Files.createDirectories(file2.getParent());
            Files.copy(file, file2);
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    });

} catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```